# Can't get Vue.js transition to work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I can't get a vue.js (version 1) transition to run. I took their code from their site. It should run the javascript console.logs!

```js
 Vue.transition('fade', {
      css: false,
      enter: function (el, done) {
        console.log('enter');
      },
      enterCancelled: function (el) {
        console.log('enterCancelled');
      },
      leave: function (el, done) {
       console.log('leave');
      },
      leaveCancelled: function (el) {
        console.log('leaveCancelled');
      }
    });

     var Vue = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        
      }
    });
```

```html
    <div id="app">
        <p transition="fade">test fade</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Vue.js’ transition system you can apply automatic transition effects when elements are inserted into or removed from the DOM.

The transition attribute can be used together with:

- v-if
- v-show
- v-for

Try that :

```js
Vue.transition('fade', {
    css: false,
 enter: function (el, done) {
  console.log('enter');
 },
 enterCancelled: function (el) {
  console.log('enterCancelled');
 },
 leave: function (el, done) {
  console.log('leave');
 },
 leaveCancelled: function (el) {
  console.log('leaveCancelled');
 }
});

var Vue = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  show: false
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.28/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
     <button @click="show = !show">{{ show ? 'hide' : 'show' }}</button>
        <p v-show="show" transition="fade">test fade</p>
</div>
```